# How to wait for multiple async http request

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'd like to ask about how to wait for multiple async http requests.

My code is like this :

```
    public void Convert(XDocument input, out XDocument output)
    {
        var ns = input.Root.Name.Namespace;

        foreach (var element in input.Root.Descendants(ns + "a"))
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri((string)element.Attribute("href"));

            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.OpenReadCompleted += ((sender, e) =>
            {
                element.Attribute("href").Value = e.Result.ToString();
            }
            );
            wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
        }

        //I'd like to wait here until above async requests are all completed.
        output = input;  
    }
```

Dose anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [article by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToParallelBasicsDontBlockYourThreadsMakeAsyncIOWorkForYou.aspx) in which he describes how to do non blocking requests. Scrolling to the end of it, there is a `public Task<bool> ValidateUrlAsync(string url)` method.

You could modify it like this (could be more robust about response reading)

```
public Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    try
    {
        request.BeginGetResponse(iar =>
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(iar);
                using(var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }                    
            }
            catch(Exception exc) { tcs.SetException(exc); }
            finally { if (response != null) response.Close(); }
        }, null);
    }
    catch(Exception exc) { tcs.SetException(exc); }
    return tsc.Task; 
}
```

So with this in hand, you could then use it like this

```
var urls=new[]{"url1","url2"};
var tasks = urls.Select(GetAsync).ToArray();
var completed = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks,
                    completedTasks =>{
                                          foreach(var result in completedTasks.Select(t=>t.Result))
                                          {
                                              Console.WriteLine(result);
                                          }
                                      });
completed.Wait();
//anything that follows gets executed after all urls have finished downloading
```

Hope this puts you in the right direction.

PS. this is probably as clear as it can get without using async/await

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).  If you can restructure your Convert method like this,

```
public void ConvertAndContinueWith(XDocument input, Action<XDocument> continueWith)
{
    var ns = input.Root.Name.Namespace;
    var elements = input.Root.Descendants(ns + "a");
    int incompleteCount = input.Root.Descendants(ns + "a").Count;
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri((string)element.Attribute("href"));

        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += ((sender, e) =>
        {
            element.Attribute("href").Value = e.Result.ToString();
            if (interlocked.Decrement(ref incompleteCount) == 0)
               // This is the final callback, so we can continue executing.
               continueWith(input);
        }
        );
        wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
    }
}
```

You then run that code like this:

```
XDocument doc = something;
ConvertAndContinueWith(doc, (finishedDocument) => {
    // send the completed document to the web client, or whatever you need to do
});
```