# How to wait for http request in VB.Net app?

Tags: json, vb.net, httprequest

I have to write in my VB.Net app a code who wait for an http request, and, when request comes, extract JSON string from it.

I know how to process JSON String

I know how to code parallel thread to wait for request.

But I don't know how to catch the request

I found this code : [How to wait for multiple async http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766172/how-to-wait-for-multiple-async-http-request)

but it's an old code (Microsoft now says that classes HttpWebResponse and HttpWebRequest used in this example are deprecated), and it seems to be hard to translate in VB : there's an instruction like "foreach(var result in completedTasks.Select(t=>t.Result))" and "t" isn't defined anywhere.

I found others examples but they all tell we how to send Http Request from Vb.Net, and I wanna receive the request in VB.Net app, and not send it from VB.Net.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: If you're writing this app from fresh, start with an [ASP Net Core project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: *`foreach(var result in completedTasks.Select(t=>t.Result))` and "t" isn't defined anywhere* - t is a variable of the type that is whatever is in the `completedTasks` list. The equivalent in VB is like this `Dim strings = {"my", "array", "of", "strings"}` `strings.Select(Function(str) str & "x")` -> `str` is a string because `strings` is an array of strings, the Select command takes a small function as an argument. It is defined that the argument named in the function shall be the type of the objects in the collection that Select is operating on

Comment: In this case the contents of `str` is first `"my"`, then `"array"`, then `"of"`, then `"strings"`. As a result this would output a sequence `"myx","arrayx","ofx","stringsx"`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this way of writing delegates, I'm more used to writing them in separate methods, it's clearer

Comment: This is one area where c# `{}` is a lot nicer than VB for sure. Those delegates there are only single line so the return and end function are dispensed with.. so long as you can form up a lambda that is a single line that returns a value (or a single line that doesn't if you do `sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x)`) it's fine. In my answer they could also be single line, its just that they make for pretty long lines so it's not always easy to make them readable in SO

Answer (score 1):

Most recently I did this with EmbedIO from Unosquare. Install the EmbedIO package using Nuget, into a new win forms (doesn't have to be; you can rip this apart later, but I used winforms to create this demo), then paste all this code over the top of your Form1.vb:

```
Imports EmbedIO
Imports EmbedIO.Routing
Imports EmbedIO.WebApi


Public Class Form1

    Private server As WebServer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim url = "http://localhost:9696/"

        server = CreateWebServer(url)
        server.RunAsync()

    End Sub



    ' Create and configure our web server.
    Private Shared Function CreateWebServer(ByVal url As String) As WebServer
        ' First, we will configure our web server by adding Modules.
        Dim server = New WebServer(
            Function(o)
                Return o.WithUrlPrefix(url).WithMode(HttpListenerMode.Microsoft)
            End Function
        ) _
        .WithWebApi("/api",
            Function(m)
                Return m.WithController(Of ApiController)()
            End Function
        )

        Return server
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ApiController
    Inherits WebApiController

    <Route(HttpVerbs.Post, "/data")>
    Public Async Function PostJsonData() As Task(Of ActionResult)
        Dim data = Await HttpContext.GetRequestDataAsync(Of MyJsonThing)()
        'install some tool like PostMan and POST some json data, like { "MyJsonThing": { "SomeProperty": "Hello" } }
        'do stuff here
        'return a response here
    End Function

    <Route(HttpVerbs.Get, "/ping")>
    Public Function Ping() As String
        Return "pong"
    End Function

End Class

Public Class MyJsonThing
    Public SomeProperty As String
End Class
```

Then run the app, open a web browser and navigate to http://localhost:9696/api/ping

You should see "pong"; if not check your firewall

The rest, is up to you!

Comment: Thank you. My VB.Net app is a WinForms app, so this code will surely fit if I arrive to integrate this package to my app